# What regular expression should I use to extract stock symbols from text file?

Tags: regex, text

I would like to extract all the symbols from a text file with a regular expression, ALLY, AMZN, AXP, AON, etc...

The following data is in a text file

```
Symbol  Holdings    Stake   Mkt. price  Value   Pct of portfolio
Ally Financial Inc  ALLY    29,000,000  9.6%    $25.59  $742,110,000    0.2%
Amazon.com, Inc.    AMZN    10,551,000  0.1%    $137.09 $1,446,436,590  0.4%
American Express Company    AXP 151,610,700 20.8%   $149.79 $22,709,766,753 6.7%
Aon PLC AON 4,335,000   2.1%    $315.64 $1,368,299,400  0.4%
Apple Inc   AAPL    915,560,382 5.9%    $176.54 $161,633,029,838    47.4%
Bank of America Corp    BAC 1,032,852,006   13.0%   $27.25  $28,145,217,164 8.3%
BYD Co. Ltd BYDDF   98,603,142  9.0%    $30.11  $2,968,940,606  0.9%
Capital One Financial Corp. COF 12,471,030  3.3%    $103.99 $1,296,862,410  0.4%
Celanese Corporation    CE  5,358,535   4.9%    $115.37 $618,214,183    0.2%
Charter Communications Inc  CHTR    3,828,941   2.6%    $409.20 $1,566,802,657  0.5%
Chevron Corporation CVX 123,120,120 6.5%    $147.07 $18,107,276,048 5.3%
Citigroup Inc   C   55,244,797  2.9%    $40.83  $2,255,645,062  0.7%
Coca-Cola Co    KO  400,000,000 9.3%    $56.98  $22,792,000,000 6.7%
```

What regular expression should I use to extract all the stock symbols in the text file?

Comment: Is that a tab delimited file?

Comment: @dawg not it is not a delimited file

Comment: It looks like it was tab delimited but has all the tabs replaced with spaces based on 4 spaces per tab. It also looks like it's missing the first column header!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another options would be to match the last set of uppercase characters before each `%` sign.

```
[A-Z]+(?=[^A-Z\n%]*%)
```

The likelihood of company names containing a `%` is probably less likely than them containing a digit/number. The `\n` is present to make sure that `[A-Z]+` is on the same line as the `%`.

[image: regex diagram]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5BA-Z%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5EA-Z%5Cn%25%5D*%25%29)</sup>

```js
const text = `\
Symbol  Holdings    Stake   Mkt. price  Value   Pct of portfolio
Ally Financial Inc  ALLY    29,000,000  9.6%    $25.59  $742,110,000    0.2%
Amazon.com, Inc.    AMZN    10,551,000  0.1%    $137.09 $1,446,436,590  0.4%
American Express Company    AXP 151,610,700 20.8%   $149.79 $22,709,766,753 6.7%
Aon PLC AON 4,335,000   2.1%    $315.64 $1,368,299,400  0.4%
Apple Inc   AAPL    915,560,382 5.9%    $176.54 $161,633,029,838    47.4%
Bank of America Corp    BAC 1,032,852,006   13.0%   $27.25  $28,145,217,164 8.3%
BYD Co. Ltd BYDDF   98,603,142  9.0%    $30.11  $2,968,940,606  0.9%
Capital One Financial Corp. COF 12,471,030  3.3%    $103.99 $1,296,862,410  0.4%
Celanese Corporation    CE  5,358,535   4.9%    $115.37 $618,214,183    0.2%
Charter Communications Inc  CHTR    3,828,941   2.6%    $409.20 $1,566,802,657  0.5%
Chevron Corporation CVX 123,120,120 6.5%    $147.07 $18,107,276,048 5.3%
Citigroup Inc   C   55,244,797  2.9%    $40.83  $2,255,645,062  0.7%
Coca-Cola Co    KO  400,000,000 9.3%    $56.98  $22,792,000,000 6.7%
`;

console.log(...text.match(/[A-Z]+(?=[^A-Z\n%]*%)/g));
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fixAzr/1)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this one will work:

`\b[A-Z]+?(?=\s+\d+)\b`

It looks for uppercase characters group followed by space and number. Realized that some companies might have the same pattern in their name.

Explanation:

```
- \b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
- Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
     +? matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
     A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- Positive Lookahead (?=\s+\d+)
    Assert that the Regex below matches
      \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
      + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
      + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      \b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/ruBdVj/1

This is from https://www.debuggex.com/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/MTQTFP/1):

```
^([A-Z].*?)\s+([A-Z]{1,5})(?=\s+\d[\d,]+)
```

You can parse name + symbol. [Try it.](https://tio.run/##TVNrT9tAEPyeX7GiIKAcx73P9wGQMSCqBhKVCvEIlUzigIVjW45TNUX0r9PdJCAsnc6@XY9nZ8YP6fTp7S0bPlWweTmfPFQFwFlVjPLycQp4Xbbpc4b7@XPLoW7yIT5cpcWMzvrDFqox1FXTjqsirzpxUczhNC/TcpinBXwrhwBxt3tDQCowIQQtgMDdBp2tK8ttwN0bxaRcVQEEVxudeJL@rUo@rCaMkDgV4vPbC9qx1Vq5bBdcLsGk9lwE3JkxjhntmA2LuiGwDLmnJZz8qZtsOoWkmtRpOV@AXvdBIppDVI@ISvBoYwFoAvcIqBSeB@adY95qcNwjYFVCv5tA3LsAw7S2K@7qnY2WljtDbLSLmAqBGfHBpq6LbCkPxHG/Sy8EaZl1gulIgeVhNZJ33BKIQ3paM4EqRjqimvGEdJSWz@TBaj4cq6mpehQngPpoxSKrkJoj0TQXi7mU58rSHjFpLFPSM4lUI64R8OYYQTh02xHg/fEpUYuYExp7FVknVvOh7pJAWMD5ghHY42i@sNFJ0jpvMQC9MvsUB@LGIemdglTMeKKHgmj86nJWoXlY2KeCY5HDHvkuWJIVaZlNswVG1aRtjvLjlZwAWKZtxKy2JMqHcKi@9rDuJGovDZOR/ghW8pQ2bdZQBCazElUjtOnSjuTs5w9q1CxSNJVcWLpKqxGBK0EMLUYhEoo56wnUEmj2u0FSnwkmV9c4KgqnBC0Mjl2xQ/MEskNyUnimvGPCRGg7GpDkbf7YVLN6lY8El0WTjGE@eGIT3tlwGgoNUFh3aKRwithgOpNqmO4mVUGBoObvPdRm@fctchreRbeOhwiWEQ/qo04R34SDcV5knU4ze5jDboFebtazdgprX17W1eug3T8YtHgrX9cgH8O/vV9bd/Hu7T3/erg9mO4sH15Qq9ftrcN9PBmM7gYjdr@zvbcJhAxvb/8B)